# unable to login in private docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am not able to login to local docker registry,getting error as:

```
"**Error response from daemon: Get http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/users/: read tcp 127.0.0.1:46779->127.0.0.1:5000: read: connection reset by peer"**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registry is most probably not behind a SSL proxy or SSL configured, so you need to configure your client-docker to allow unsecure registrys, see https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: I configured unsecured registry using self singed certificate. Now I am getting different error message as " Get https://myregistrydomain.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup myregistrydomain.com on 192.168.2.5:53: no such host".